# Minimal to no intervention for Linux installation

Tags: linux, windows, system-installation

I need to replace a Windows OS running on x86 devices with a custom Linux distro. I need to automate the process as much as possible. Ideally, plug in a USB stick or connect to a Network server, run the installation, and it completes without intervention.

What level of automation is possible? Are there tools for this?

Assume that data care is already solved. Also PXE is possible and USB ports are available.

Comment: Full automation is possible. "Inserting the USB stick, let it boot and the install routine does the rest.". Linux provides its own tools for it. Usually you install 1time a Linux system manual, after installation an install log has been created, this log can be used to automate another installation.

Comment: Please give us a bit more information about the hardware. Are all devices identical? Can you take an image and just copy the image onto the relevant storage media?

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more. What distribution do you want to install? 
For RedHat-like distros, it's pretty easy to make a custom Kickstart bootable device, which will install a pre-defined image.  See [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/index#performing_an_automated_installation_using_kickstart)

Comment: Thanks, @Popup. It would be a Debian based distro.